# Function Expressions: Why are they used?

Tags: javascript

I have just started teaching myself JavaScript --and programming-- and I am kind of confused about Function Expressions. Basically, I understand the point of Functions, but I am trying to learn why a Function Expression would be used in place of a Function. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: when you don't need to refer to a function later, you can use an expression. this is nice because functions in JS are not used just for callable subroutines, they provide scope and timing features as well.

Comment: one point to consider... function functionName will fire immediately if its nested inside another function.

Comment: So from what I am to understand, function expressions are are used for code which only needs to be run once within a task, rather than being repeatedly called?

Comment: It's just like non-functions; sometimes we feel the need to name a value, and sometimes we just use the value directly. (Are you confused about why someone would write `alert("Hello!")` rather than `var msg = "Hello!"; alert(msg)`?)